# how to return multiple reporters in protractor afterlaunch function that are wrapped up in promises?

Tags: javascript, promise, protractor, jasmine-reporters

I have the following reporters

```
 afterLaunch: function (exitCode) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        reporter1.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });

    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        reporter2.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
    });
}
```

Each of the above reporters have their own afterlaunch that would be expected to execute once the afterlaunch in the ptor.conf file is executed.

But apparently because of the `return new Promise`, the first report gets returned from there itself and the execution stops there.

How would it possible to return both the reports at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (or the `protractor.promise.all()` if you are operating the webdriver promises):

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    reporter1.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
});

var promise2 = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    reporter2.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
});

return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
```

Comment: the above solution works perfectly, but this is a part of the continuous integration job in Jenkins. So what's happening is that the promise resolves so the exit code becomes 0, even when a test fails hence overwriting the exit code of the job. So even though its a legit failure the jenkins shows as passed. I need to preserve the original value of exitCode that is being passed to the above reports for the jenkins job to function as expected. How can we prevent this?

Comment: @pj013 got it, could you please create a separate question for this problem? This way, more people can potentially help to solve it. Thanks!

Comment: any idea on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41386162/promises-change-the-exitcode-of-the-jenkins-job-how-to-prevent-this/41389265#41389265