# Promises change the exitCode of the jenkins job, how to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jenkins, promise, protractor, jasmine-reporters

I have the following reporters in the protractor.conf file:

```
 var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    reporter1.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
});

var promise2 = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    reporter2.afterLaunch(resolve.bind(this, exitCode));
});

return Promise.all([promise1, promise2]);
```

Each of the above reporters have their own afterlaunch that would be expected to execute once the afterlaunch in the ptor.conf file is executed.

This is a part of the continuous integration job in Jenkins. So what's happening is that the promise resolves so the exit code of the process becomes 0, even when a test fails hence overwriting the exit code of the job. So even though its a legit failure the jenkins shows the entire job as PASSED. I need to preserve the original value of `exitCode` that is being passed to the above reports for the jenkins job to function as expected. How can we prevent this?

Comment: Which reporter is this? What test framework are you using in Protractor?

Comment: This is a jasmine reporter which works fine, but i need the returned promise not to change the exitcode for the process

Comment: Does the Promise reject? Can `reporter.afterLaunch` throw an error? If not, then I'd say the Promise is working as intended.

Comment: I need the promise to reject to preserve the exitcode, but because it resolves the exitcode is changed as jenkins picks up the exitcode of thr last condition that is executed

Answer (score 0):

assuming `exitCode` is a `Number` the `resolve.bind(this, exitCode)` returns a function whose first parameter is bound to the value of `exitCode` at the time those vars (promise1 and promise2) are declared

so any changes to exitCode between the time the promise is created and when the reporter1.afterLaunch callback gets fired will not be reflected in the value those promises resolve to,

i.e. assuming exitCode is zero when the promises are created, then the resolved value will be zero regardless of what exitCode is changed to

On the other hand

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    reporter1.afterLaunch(() => resolve(exitCode));
});
```

or

```
var promise1 = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    reporter1.afterLaunch(function() {
        resolve(exitCode);
    });
});
```

will resolve to the current value of exitCode